# How to keep current language when invalide session in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

My application is supporting more then language. Problem is when user logout (which means I call `getSession().invalidate()`) then current language is lost and there is created new session with default language.

Language is sets via link:

```
add(new Link<Void>("goSk") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        getSession().setLocale(new Locale("sk", "SK"));
    }
});

add(new Link<Void>("goEn") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        getSession().setLocale(Locale.US);
    }
});
```

So question is how should I keep current language when I invaliate session

Comment: Have you considered saving your user preferences in a database?

Comment: yes but this is the options which I want to avoid because when user logout then there is no user and I thought wicket support some way how to keep some stuff with invalidated session

Comment: In principle you need to start a new session (with a "public user" pirncipal), passing the locale as parameter to the public page where the new session starts.

Answer (score 4):

Better use a Cookie for anonymous users.
Before invalidating save the lang in a cookie. In YourSession#getLocale() use the cookie if there is no user.

Comment: I am not sure but invalidate also delete cookies

Comment: It deletes the session cookie, but not any custom cookies.

Comment: I would also advise you to take this solution. It also saves a lot of clutter in your PageParameters.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: invalidating session does not allow to reset a parameter in the session.
a viable solution I successfully tested is to use PageParameters

```
Locale currentLocale=getSession().getLocale();
session.invalidate();//clear all session data
PageParameters pp=new PageParameters();
pp.add("locale", currentLocale.getLanguage());
setResponsePage(<you class>.class,pp);
```

and in the page you specified in setResponsePage you have to provide a constructor with PageParameters something like

```
 public class Login extends BasePage {
    public Login(PageParameters pp) {
        //your code here
        logger.debug("login user"+pp.getString("locale"));
    }
```

Wicket passes the parameter via query string
I tried this with a working test case

Comment: yes I try this but it doesnt work because invalidate just set some parameter to invalidate session on next request and then there is created whole new session

Comment: but why should I invalidate session immediately ? PS: it is still not working because after invalidate or invalidateNow there is still creating whole new session via newSession in AuthenticatedWebApplication class

Comment: I did not try with a test case but I think because you can re-set the locale without losing it at the next request

Comment: you were rigth invalidate does not allow to reuse session parameters, I found a solution with PageParameters